# LeetCode compile error with mapToInt, works locally

Tags: java

I am trying to use `mapToInt` to transform an integer into an integer array. Right now, the following code compiles and works for me locally but when I submit to LeetCode it gives me a compile error `Line 29: error: invalid method reference`. Line 29 is where I am using `mapToInt`. I cannot figure out why there is a compile error in LeetCode and not for me locally.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int digits[] =

         {
             1,
             9,
             9,
             9
         };
         plusOne(digits);
         }

    public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {

        if (digits.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                ("Array is empty!");
        }

        else {

            int integer = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) integer += Math.pow(10,i) * digits[digits.length - i - 1];
            integer = integer + 1;
            int[] result = Arrays.stream(result).mapToInt(int::integer).toArray();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
            return result;
        }

    } 
}
```

**UPDATE:** This does not compile for me locally anymore either. I must have been mistaken previously. It's now throwing a `cannot find symbol` error locally.

Comment: Could you kindly explain what you think that the line `int[] result = Arrays.stream(result).mapToInt(int::integer).toArray();` does? I get the first compile error already at `Arrays.stream(result)`: "variable 'result' might not have been initialized"

Comment: I am not quite sure as I am new to the Java 8 streams and lambdas. I have been thinking that it would be better to abandon the lambdas in this case and break the functions out in a more verbose fashion. I have been trying to do that without much success so far. I just wanted to convert an integer into an int array and this seemed to be one way. It appears that the process is something like convert the integer to a stream, convert the stream to an integer array but it seems that `mapToInt` will not work for this because it requires an object.

Comment: It would (sort of ) work if you could create a function that takes an integer and produces a stream of int values from its digits. Then you could write `int[] result = Arrays.stream(value).flatMap(i -> yourHypotheticalFunction(i)).toArray();`. But that would mean that you still would have to write a function/method `IntStream yourHypotheticalFunction(int value) {}`

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Arrays.stream(int[] array)` returns an `IntStream` here which does not have a `mapToInt` function.

Use something as simple as:

```
String[] array = Stream.of( ... ).toArray( String[]::new );
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not compile. It throws a `cannot find symbol` error (locally). I do need an integer array, not a string array so I adjusted the above accordingly to `int[] result = Stream.of(integer).toArray(int[]::result);`. I also looked here and it seems that the `intStream` does have a `mapToInt` method, at least so it seems. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html.

Comment: Umm what about something like `Integer[] result = Stream.of(1,2,3).toArray(Integer[]::result);`

Comment: I can try this but need to return a primitive `int`.

Comment: I tried `int[] result = Stream.of(integer).toArray(int::result);` but still getting cannot find symbol. Also for `int[] result = Stream.of(integer).toArray(int[]::result);` same error.

Comment: No, look at my comment properly. You have to use a wrapper class!

Comment: OK, I have tried this `Integer[] result = Stream.of(integer).toArray(Integer[]::result);` but I do get an `incompatible type` error: `Integer cannot be converted to int[]` when I try to return `result` because I need to return an `int[]`. Let me see about converting the Integer array to an int arry.

Comment: What is integer here? Can you post three lines of your code here? I think it's maybe because somewhere later in your code you are trying to use `result` as an int[].

Comment: Do this after previous code I wrote `int[] newResult = result.toArray();`

Comment: @emanic I can't find a `mapToInt` method in the list of methods. The example on top of the javadoc uses a `mapToInt` method, but this one must clearly be a method of the normal `Stream` interface, because this method accepts a function the converts some unspecified object type into an int (in `w -> w.getWeight()` the parameter w cannot be an int, since integers don't have a `getWeight()` method).